# mdx query to calculate average between date range

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I am hoping to get some help to calculate the average between date ranges. Start date would be the time dimension and end date = start date - 13. Or is there a way we can use iff statement to calculate the average with date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `AVG` in `MDX`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/avg-mdx

The functions signature is this:

```
Avg( Set_Expression [ , Numeric_Expression ] )
```

So the Set_Expression will be the dates and the optional Numeric_Expression could be say a measure.

If you have a specific date such as `[Ship Date].[Date].[Date].[10 Feb 2018]` then you can go backwards using the lag function - then you can create a range using a colon operator.

Therefore you might end up with an expression like this:

```
AVG(
   [Ship Date].[Date].[Date].[10 Feb 2018].lag(13)
 : [Ship Date].[Date].[Date].[10 Feb 2018]
 ,[Measures].[Revenue]
)
```

So the above is not so dynamic but if the hierarchy `[Ship Date].[Date].[Date]` is ON ROWS then you can use the CURRENTMEMBER function:

```
AVG(
   [Ship Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.lag(13)
 : [Ship Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER
 ,[Measures].[Revenue]
)
```

Comment: Hi - The above calculated measure worked for me. I have a dimension with values as Type a, Type b. How can I add only type b value to be calculated in the calculation below : AVG(
   [Ship Date].[Date].[Date].[10 Feb 2018].lag(13)
 : [Ship Date].[Date].[Date].[10 Feb 2018]
 ,[Measures].[Revenue]
)

Comment: If you cross join the time period set, inside the avg function with the target type, then that should limit the average to only that type

Comment: You could up the answer if you like ;)